# Model create or bulkCreate promise in seed file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, seed

I have some promise chain to add data. If I use it "normally" in a JavaScript file, I start with Node.js or call it some other way, it works (more or less - different question).

But if I want to use it at a sequelize seed file with the sequelize-cli (sequelize db:seed:all), the promises won't work. OK, there's an error that runs into the `.catch` chain, but the `.then` won't work...

The promise fields are all undefined...

I know I can use bulkInsert, but why do I use an ORM if I "have to" use raw SQL, especially if I have links between the tables that point to uuid's?

I defined the models, had a "normal" migrate file, and want the "start" data with a seed. Do I need something separate to use create / bulkCreate promises?

Did I miss something in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself with many tries and the answer of this: 
[Sequelize dynamic seeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43151613/sequelize-dynamic-seeding)

the associations needed to be fixed at the models:

```
User.associate = function(models) {
  User.belongsToMany(
    models.Role, {
      through: 'user_role',
    }
  );
};
```

and

```
Role.associate = function(models) {
  Role.belongsToMany(
    models.User, {
      through: 'user_role',
    }
  );
};
```

and the m:n table needed this:

```
....
.then(() => {
  queryInterface.createTable('user_role', {
    userUuid: {
      type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      references: {
        model: 'User',
        key: 'uuid',
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    roleUuid: {
      type: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      references: {
        model: 'Role',
        key: 'uuid',
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    createdAt: { allowNull: false, type: Sequelize.DATE },
    updatedAt: { allowNull: false, type: Sequelize.DATE },
  });
}).then(() => {
  return queryInterface.addConstraint(
    'user_role',
    ['userUuid', 'roleUuid'], {
      unique: true,
      type: 'primary key',
      name: 'userrole_pkey',
    }
  );
});
```

renamed the fields to be like the generated ones from sequelize